# apply_async in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, kernel, multiprocessing, jupyter

I'm developing some parallelizable simulations in Jupiter Notebooks before deploying them to a large, standalone server using multiprocessing, but I cannot interrupt the kernel while using `apply_async`. This was not a problem when I was using `multiprocessing.Process`. The following chunk runs just fine, but cannot be interrupted:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    for sim in simulations:
        pool.apply_async(my_fx, args=(sim,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Where does this problem lie and how can it be fixed?

edit: Python v2.7, Jupyter v4.3

Comment: What OS are you running on. Windows has know multiprocessing issues in Jupyter.

Comment: Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). I eventually figured out that KeyBoard Interrupt only quits one worker at a time and that they aren't sharing this information. I found a work around (http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2014/01/14/python-%7C-multiprocessing-and-interrupts/)